# structuredClone not keeping Date type

Tags: javascript, node.js, structured-clone

I'm using the `structuredClone()` global function in NodeJs 20.4.1 to clone an object that has a property of type `Date`. However, the clone object is not keeping the type of this object.

```js
const originalObj = { myDate: new Date("2023-01-01 00:00:00") };
const cloneObj = structuredClone(originalObj);

console.log({ originalDate: originalObj.myDate, instanceofDate: originalObj.myDate instanceof Date });
console.log({ cloneDate: cloneObj.myDate, instanceofDate: cloneObj.myDate instanceof Date });
```

The output is:

```bash
{ originalDate: 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, instanceofDate: true }
{ cloneDate: 2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z, instanceofDate: false }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or there is something wrong with `structuredClone()`?

Comment: When I try your code in Chrome it returns `instanceOfDate: true` in both cases.

Comment: It works correctly in Chrome, so this sounds like a node.js bug.

Comment: I checked this with v20.4.0 and it works fine. Note there is no v20.4.1 as far as I can make out.